# Why isn't $f(x)=0$ ever mentioned as a solution to $f'(x)=f(x)$?

Tags: derivatives

I know that $f(x)=e^x$ is the accepted and useful solution to $f'(x)=f(x)$, but why isn't $f(x)=0$ ever mentioned as a solution as well? Is it simply because it's not useful?

Comment: $f(x)=Ce^x$ for all constants $C$ are all the solutions.

Comment: probably. Note that the ODE gives $a e^x$ where $a$ is a constant. This then includes $a=0.$

Comment: It's called the trivial solution for a reason. It's boring.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, I had never even seen it as a trivial solution with a dismissal, which I always find surprising when I come across it.

Comment: The source which mentions $e^x$ as solution of $f'=f$ does not mention $0$ as a solution of the differential equation for the same reason that it doesn't mention $2e^x$.

Comment: @Chuck That's the joke. The solution $f(x) = 0$ gives nothing interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f'(x) = f(x)$ is linear differential equation, if $f(x)$ is solution then so is $kf(x)$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}$. So the solution is of the form $f(x) = Ae^x$ for $A \in \mathbb{R}$. Here $A$ is determined by some given initial condition.

The choice of $A =0$ gives the solution $f(x) = 0$.